# How to remove mixed content warnings in WP Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer, https

In a bit of a pickle as I am having this warning message (in the developer's menu of google) saying I am trying to connect with google fonts through http even though my site is set up to use https.

The actual error is as below and only occurs when I'm using the WP customizer. Thing is, I can't change any of my selected google fonts in the customizer because of this error.

> load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,underscore,jquery-ui-widget,j…:3 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://japanfo.com/wp-admin/customize.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fjapanfo.com%2Flistings%2Fnagoya-castle%2F' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanken|Source+Sans+Pro|Playfair+Disp…ns+Pro|Delius|Lato|Flamenco|Lato|Vidaloka|Lato|Copse|Raleway&text=AaBbCcJa'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Tried everything and so am reaching out here.

Comment: Before we start guessing, could you tell us what the "everything" is you have already tried? (like making sure there is no hardcoded 'http' in your theme)

Comment: Sure, my apologies.

I'm not a developer so please excuse my ignorance and use of simple terminology at times.

I looked through all the stylesheets and could find no http references for google fonts. I also scanned all the files in the theme for references and nothing.

I guess my everything is not all that comprehensive but it's all I know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in the way your fonts are being enqueued in the `functions.php` file of your theme. Look for instances of [`wp_register_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and see if you find the google fonts api there with `http`. It's possible that your theme has its customizer settings in a different php file, so you should probably also check for a file called `customizer.php` or `theme-mods.php` or so.

Beware that if you change theme files and the theme is updated, you will loose your modifications. The royal way would be to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice. The theme developers came back to me after a few days and suggested completely deleting and reinstalling a customizer plugin for the theme. This did the trick of getting rid of the error....thank god. Sadly it hasn't fixed the error I was trying to fix as there seems to be a JS conflict on the page stopping the customizer working.....

Comment: You could always make that into a new question